# -ObjC flag causes duplicate symbols on iPhone simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-simulator, static-linking

My project is dependent on a .framework which includes categories. To make the categories work I've added `-ObjC -all_load` to my "Other Linker Flags" in Xcode. This works perfectly on a device, but when I build and run in the simulator I get `duplicate symbols for architecture i386`.

I have also tried using the linker flag `-force_load ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework` which also works fine on the device but not the simulator.

What goes wrong and how do I fix it?